# Flashlight apk version is Different?

Tags: android, version-control, version, led, flashlight

I have flashlight apk with two problem.
İf I use camera, camera.params. My apk working with lower versions Android 5. THen if I use camera2 and camera.manager, My app working with Android 5 and higger versions.

I wanna work with Android version 4 and higger, work with all versions.
How can I do this?

Pls help me for this, thanks.

```js
package com.hallac.erdogan.spechflash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btnSwitch;
    ImageButton flashlight;

    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Camera.Parameters params;
    private CameraManager mCameraManager;
    private String mCameraId;




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//full keran ile ilgili ayarlar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,//full keran ile ilgili ayarlar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//full keran ile ilgili ayarlar


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // flash switch button
        btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buton);
        flashlight=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.flashlight);


        // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);



        // get the camera
        getCamera();

        // displaying button image
        toggleButtonImage();


        // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
        btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    // turn off flash
                    turnOffFlash();
                } else {
                    // turn on flash
                    turnOnFlash();
                }
            }
        });


        flashlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent= new Intent(getBaseContext(),SpeakNow.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }


    // Get the camera
    private void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            }
        }
    }



    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }




            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
            toggleButtonImage();
        }

    }


    private void turnOffFlash() {
        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;
            toggleButtonImage();
        }
    }


    private void toggleButtonImage(){
        if(isFlashOn){
            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
        }else{
            btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);
        }
    }






    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // on pause turn off the flash
        //  turnOffFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // on resume turn on the flash
        if(hasFlash)
            turnOnFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // on starting the app get the camera params
        getCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        Log.d("Camera","Back Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // on stop release the camera
        //   if (camera != null) {
        //       camera.release();
        //      camera = null;
        // }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi again, I found solution for this.
I am using only sdk asking for my code in to java class. Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <Build.VERSION_CODES.M This is enough for the android versions. thanks.